# Using tabularx increases the tab counter by two

Tags: numbering, captions, tabularx

In my document I use some `tabularx` tables. Now I found out, that every time I use it the table counter in the caption increases by two.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X X X X}
    A & B & C & D
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{A table.}
\end{table}
```

With this code, the caption reads `Table 2: ...` but when I use `\begin{tabular}` the caption reads `Table 1: ...`.

Can somebody explain me this behaviour?

I found out, that if I disable the `ltablex` package the numbering starts with 1 again.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X X X X}
    A & B & C & D
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{A table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE, not just a code snippet, that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Please turn this into a minimal complete document that shows the problem. If I put this into a document it produces the correct output (with the `\ra{1.2}` commented out.)

Comment: I added it. I also found out, that if I disable the ltablex package the numbering is correct again.

Comment: @Werner so I when using tabularx the `\caption` belongs into the `\begin{tabularx} ... \end{tabularx}` and when I use `tabular` then the caption belongs outside of it?

Comment: That is the main reason why I prefer ltxtable to ltablex ltablex essentially makes every tabularx into a longtable